# Determine type of element from list

Tags: python, pem

My python code is reading a PEM file containing certificate and private key using PEM package.

**Code:**

```
import pem
Mylist = pem.parse_file(r"C:\Desktop\MyPemFile.pem")
for ele in Mylist:
     print(type(ele))
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'pem._core.RSAPrivateKey'>
<class 'pem._core.Certificate'>
<class 'pem._core.Certificate'>
<class 'pem._core.Certificate'>
<class 'pem._core.Certificate'>
```

Now, I am trying to identity the type of each element from the list and do certain action.
But, I am unable to determine the type. How do I modify my code to determine type of every element?

**Code:**

```
Mylist = pem.parse_file(r"C:\Desktop\MyPemFile.pem")
for ele in Mylist:
     if type(ele) == 'pem._core.RSAPrivateKey':
             print(ele) # Control doesn't go here. 
     else:
             print("Invalid type")
```

**Output:**

```
Invalid type
Invalid type
Invalid type
Invalid type
Invalid type
```

Comment: `isinstance` is usual tool for checking class (or subclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should be an easy way to import the types themselves (not  the string identifiers) from `pem`. something probably like `from pem import RSAPrivateKey` (i've never used the library). then you can just do:

```
if isinstance(ele, RSAPrivateKey):
    print(ele)
```